# Translation from maple to sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, maple

okay, so I have this piece of code that I have made on the software MAPLE and I need to tranform the code into the sql language (on oracle). I'd be really thankful if any of you could help me or maybe even just point out some applications, websites to achieve this. I have a table in whih there are listed parents and their respective children and the code is supposed to create another table with aunt, uncles and their nieces.
heres the code:

```
`use DocumentTools,Statistics,ListTools in 
#Matrice=tabella 
M:=Matrix([l,m]);
#nulla di importante, solo per la resa grafica
SetProperty('m',visibleRows,2);
SetProperty('m',visibleColumns,Count(m));
inta:=[];
for i from 1 to Count(m) do
    inta:=[inta[],300];
    end;
SetProperty('m',rowNames,["genitori","figli"]);
SetProperty('m',columnWidths, inta);
SetProperty('m',update);
#inizializzazione di liste
p:=[];
zii:=[];
nipoti:=[];
#m è una lista formata da sotto liste, per usare il comando del pacchetto(libreria) ListTools, Search, devo trasformarla in una lista unica
for j from 1 to Count(m) do
     p:=[p[],op(m[j])];
end do;
#l è anche una lista di liste, dunque 2 cicli per selezionare ogni elemento
    for k from 1 to Count(l) do
    for K from 1 to Count(l[k]) do
    #se un figlio è anche un genitore, allora in quella famiglia ci sono nipoti e ci possono essere zii. Controllo se un padre è anche figlio
    s:=Search(l[k][K],p);
    if s=0 then
        else
            #Se lo fosse individuo la lista che lo contiene in quelle dei figli
            for jj from 1 to Count(m) do
                num:=Search(p[s],m[jj]);
                if num=0 then
                    else
                        lista_n:=[];
                    for cont from 1 to Count(m[jj]) do
                        if m[jj][cont]=p[s] then
                            #Tramite l'if escludo dalla lista il genitore
                            else
                            lista_n:=[lista_n[],m[jj][cont]];                   
                    end if;
                    end do;
                    zii:=[zii[],lista_n];
                        end if;
              end do;
              #I nipoti sono in posizione uguale al genitore, ma nell'altra lista
            nipoti:=[nipoti[],m[k]];
            end if;
    end; end;
#i succesivi for e if servono nel caso in cui ci siano zii da entrambi i genitori
for lol from 2 to Count(nipoti) do
    if nipoti[lol]=nipoti[lol-1] then   
    #i nipoti comuni sono consecutivi poichè i genitori originali lo erano nella lista ordinata (spero che si capisca cosa voglio dire). 
    #Dunque inserisco una lista nell 'altra e elimina quella stessa lista ridifinendola e utilizzando un if e un for
    zii[lol]:=[op(zii[lol]),op(zii[lol-1])];
    zii[lol-1]:=[elimina];
        else
            end if;
Zii:=[];
for contatore from 1 to Count(zii) do
if zii[contatore]=[elimina] then
    else
        Zii:=[Zii[],zii[contatore]];
        end if;
    end;
    end;
    #Nulla di importante per il codice, apparte il comando MakeUnique che elimina i doppioni (dovrebbe essere superfluo ma non ho più testato).
inta1:=[];
for i from 1 to max([Count(zii),Count(nipoti)]) do
    inta1:=[inta1[],300];
    end;
DataTable:=Matrix([MakeUnique(Zii),MakeUnique(nipoti)]);
SetProperty('T',visibleColumns,max([Count(zii),Count(nipoti)]));
SetProperty('T',visibleRows,2);
SetProperty('T',columnWidths, inta1);
SetProperty('T',rowNames,["zii","nipoti"]);
SetProperty('T',update);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

It should not be complex to translate this code into [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) that is a complete programming language so should be capable of doing everything. You can implement it as a stored procedure and later access it also from SQL statements.

If there are some mathematical constructs, I suggest to use Maple code generation feature, producing the code of some not too specific language (even C or FORTRAN may do) that can be later converted into PL/SQL by hand. However the code as it is seems having no any complex mathematical features, while I would obviously understand it much more completely be the comments in English and not Italian.